# Unsupported Media Type with Spring Boot and Serverless

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, yaml

I am building application with Spring Boot (Serverless project) to deploy in AWS Lambda. I have a method that consumes **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. When I call method in localhost 415 appear:

> Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not
>   supported

I attach method code and yaml configuration, I think that problem is Serverless configuration, because this method works in other project (NON-Serverless).

**Method**:

```
 @PostMapping(name = "/createpayment", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String createPayment(@RequestBody Payload payload) throws StripeException, IOException, MessagingException { 
         ...
 }
```

**Yaml**:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: AWS Serverless Sansaru Payments - com.sansarushop.payments::sansaru-payments
Globals:
  Api:
    EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL


Resources:
  SansaruPaymentsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: com.example.payments.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: target/example-payments-1.0-SNAPSHOT-lambda-package.zip
      MemorySize: 512
      Policies: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: any
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: 'prod'

Outputs:
  SansaruPaymentsApi:
    Description: URL for application
    Value: !Sub 'https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/ping'
    Export:
      Name: ExamplePaymentsApi
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with mediatype application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Spring Boot doesn't understand this with RequestBody. So, if you want to use , please remove the @RequestBody annotation from method.

```
@PostMapping(name = "/createpayment", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String createPayment(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) throws StripeException, IOException, MessagingException { 
         ...
 }
```